# Function Declaration is Incompatible Between .h and .c Files After the Introduction of External Typedef Struct

Tags: c

I've split up my program into different `.c` and `.h.` files with functions in `.c` and function prototypes, structs and typedefs in the `.h` files.

Let's say I have `car.c` and `car.h`. These include functions that take in a `Sensor* sensor` however `Sensor` is a `typedef struct` from `sensor.h`. So I simply write `#include "sensor.h"` in `car.h`. Now both `car.c` and `car.h` have access to `Sensor` and my IDE seems to confirm that.

The problem arises from the functions themselves that argue `Sensor* sensor`. Let's say I have `void printCarSensors(Sensor* sensor1, Sensor* sensor2) {}`. Both `car.c` and `car.h` will be happy with the `Sensor*` type. `car.c` will be entirely happy, no errors at all.

However, `car.h` will have a red line under `printCarSensors` and the error will be:

```
declaration is incompatible with "void printCarSensors(Sensor* sensor1,
Sensor* sensor2) " (declared at line 26 of "C:\Users\user\Desktop
WorkingFiles\car.c")
```

In `sensor.h` I would have

```
typedef struct sensor Sensor;

struct sensor{
    int time;
    int speed;
    int acceleration;
    int temp;
};
```

Hopefully that all makes sense and any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: try putting the typedef after the struct, or better yet do it together as typedef struct sensor { ... } Sensor;  also what does the compiler rather than the IDE say?

Comment: What is the declaration of `printCarSensors` from `car.h`?  You seem focused on the incompatibility being caused by `Sensor`, but how do you know?

Comment: We need to see a minimal copy of `car.c`, `car.h`, and `sensor.h` that reproduces the problem. See [mcve].

Comment: Does the code compile or not, and if not what is the exact compiler error? Just "*a red line under*" could be an artifact of whatever smart editor you are using.

Comment: Edit the question to provide a [mre].